# Warning while loading data using tensorflow in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, io, operating-system

How do I load a data set using tensorflow in jupyter notebook. I tried to do it but got the following warning

```
"%%capture
session = tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
tf.saved_model.loader.load(session, ['serve'], model_path)"
```

the above is the code i used to load the data

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-7-43e69c73592c>:2: load (from tensorflow.python.saved_model.loader_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This function will only be available through the v1 compatibility library as tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load or tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load. There will be a new function for importing SavedModels in Tensorflow 2.0.
INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
INFO:tensorflow:The specified SavedModel has no variables; no checkpoints were restored.
```

Comment: You can try to use `tf.keras.models.load_model` to load model. For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#whole-model_saving_loading). You can tutorials to load [image](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images), [CSV](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv), [Numpy](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy), [pandas.df](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe) and [text](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/text). Thanks!

Comment: Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks! – TFer2 1 min ago   Edit   Delete